# getting error while binding array from server to html part on AngularJS with Asp .Net WebApi

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive

I get some errors on chrome.
I suspect the html is loading faster than the array and this makes the problem ( sync ).

I imported an array from the Server.

Then I used it in the html part for binding the array items to:
Paths, id and tag elements.

They part point to the first point I use the array binding on the html. If I hardcode something instead - It goes to the next point I bind the array to html.

```
<body>
    <section class="memory-game">
        <div class="memory-card" id="{{images[0].imageName}}">
            <img class="front-face" src="/src/assets/images/cards/{{images[0].imageName}}"  alt="{{images[0].imageName}}" />
            <img class="back-face" src="/src/assets/images/cards/savanna.jpg" alt="savanna" />
        </div>

public images: ImageModel[];
constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private imageService: ImagesService , private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
    const observable = this.imageService.getAllPhotos();
    observable.subscribe(images => {
        this.images = images.concat(images);
        console.log(this.images);
        this.images = this.shuffleArr(this.images);
        console.log(this.images);
        this.checkIfLogin();
        this.game();

    });
```

I want the code will be without errors.
Now the code is working well ( binding between array & html)
But... I have the errors from chrome as  attached picture link:
[chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrgRG.png)

all errors lead to this line on html (the first div).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be Angular code, not Angularjs. However you could fix the error by using **`safe navigation operator(?)`**. The error happens because images array seems does not have any elements in it.

```
<img class="front-face" src="/src/assets/images/cards/{{images[0]?.imageName}}"  alt="{{images[0]?.imageName}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It didn't solve the problem. Chrome error is :Cannot read property '0' of undefined   .  Well, I think that i need more than bypass. I need to solve the problem why is the html is not sync to the array loading from the webApi server. Any suggestions ?